# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.get_chat_member_count' was never awaited

Tags: python, aiogram

День добрый господа.

Хотел бы получить кол-во участников в группе Телеграмм, но пишет че-то про коротину,пробовал ЗаГуГлИтЬ - не work. Строго не оценивайте, делаю бота первый раз.

**Код:**

```
async def send_user_value(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    all_users = bot.get_chat_member_count(chat_id=chanell)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await call.message.answer(text="Всего пользователей: " + str(all_users))
```

***Что пишет, если запустить:***

`Всего пользователей: <coroutine object Bot.get_chat_member_count at 0x0000020B43947220>`

**Полная ошибка:**

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.get_chat_member_count' was never awaited
  await call.message.answer(text="Всего пользователей: {0}".format(bot.get_chat_member_count(chat_id=chanell)))
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Как исправить данный вопрос? Заранее, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делай так

```
all_users = await bot.get_chat_member_count(chat_id=chanell)
```

Так как эта функция является асинхронной то ее нужно await`ить

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Благодарю Вас!